# How to get the latest rows for each user ID in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5, greatest-n-per-group

> ```
> id  user_id  name    qty     datetime
> --- ---------  ----    ----    -----------
> 1   1           a      5       2019-12-01 12:26:01
> 2   2           b      3       2019-12-13 12:26:02
> 3   1           c      4       2019-12-13 12:26:03
> 4   2           a      2       2019-12-25 12:26:04
> 5   1           c      2       2019-12-21 12:26:06
> ```

i Want the this data

> ```
> id  user_id  name    qty     datetime
> --- ---------  ----    ----    -----------
> 5   1           c      2       2019-12-21 12:26:06
> 4   2           a      2       2019-12-25 12:26:04
> ```

using laravel and also if possible then what will be the sql query for it

Comment: So latest rows for each user ID?

Comment: yes @vivek_23 thats right

Answer (score 2):

**Models:**

*Users:* id, name, email, etc...
*Orders:* user_id, qty, name, datetime etc..

**Model Query:**

```
Orders::orderBy('datetime', 'desc')->get()->unique('user_id');
```

**DB Query**

```
DB::table('orders')->orderBy('datetime', 'desc')->get()->unique('user_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure SQL, you can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.datetime = (
    select max(t1.datetime) from mytable t1 where t1.user_id = t.user_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

or an uncorrelated subquery...

```
select x.*
from mytable x
join (
    select user_id, max(t1.datetime) datetime from mytable group by user_id
) y
on y.user_id = x.user_id
and y.datetime = x.datetime
```